# Focus Out event for TLFTextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield, flash-cs5

I'm having an issue where I don't get a "FOCUS_OUT" event called when I click around the stage. I do get the "FOCUS_IN" event when I click the TLFTextField. Not sure what the problem may be, any hints or ideas would be great. I did already do some Google searches, but didnt quite find anything useful.

Here is some of the code I have:

```
txt_search.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);
txt_search.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onFocusOut);

private function onFocusOut(e:FocusEvent):void
    {
        trace("--Search Field-- :: FocusOut");
        if(txt_search.text == '')
        {
            txt_search.text = _defaultText;
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

private function onMouseEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(txt_search.text != '' && txt_search.text != _defaultText)
    {
        //do search
        trace("--Search Feeds--");
    }
    else
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The "FOCUS_OUT" event is called when I tab. Is there some other event listener I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest, try playing around with all four of these

```
txt_search.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, inHandler);
txt_search.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, outHandler);
txt_search.addEventListener(FocusEvent.KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE, keyFocusChangeHandler);
txt_search.addEventListener(FocusEvent.MOUSE_FOCUS_CHANGE, mouseFocusChangeHandler);
```

Then, you can always work around events like focus events by adding listeners elsewhere.  For instance, if the focus is **IN** on one object, that means it's **OUT** on all others.  I use that fact sometimes when I'm writing things like this.  Often, I can get away with using only one event or the other.  You may not need both.